# Incrementing pointers for *char in a while loop

Tags: c++, string, loops, pointers, traversal

Here is what I have:

```
char* input = new char [input_max]
char* inputPtr = iput;
```

I want to use the inputPtr to traverse the input array. However I am not sure what will correctly check whether or not I have reached the end of the string:

```
while (*inputPtr++)
{
    // Some code
}
```

or

```
while (*inputPtr != '\0')
{
    inputPtr++;
    // Some code
}
```

or a more elegant option?

Comment: They are equivalent. Of course, you must make sure there actually is a `\0` in the array.

Comment: This is a question of what you put in your array. Are you sure you have an `'\0'` element in your array? If there is, are you sure the `'\0'` element is in the bounds of the array?

Comment: I am new to programming so excuse me if what I am about to ask is redundant, but is '\0' == 0?

Comment: _"is '\0' == 0"_ - Yep. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0).

Comment: @juanchopanza 

So does that mean that the while statement first checks the value of inputPtr after being dereferenced, and then increments the the memory address stored in inputPtr??? (I am still new to pointers, so I get confused when it comes to this stuff)

Comment: Postfix operator `++` increases something and returns the old value. So `*i++` has the effect of de-referencing `i`, *then* increasing its value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming input string is null-terminated:

```
for(char *inputPtr = input; *inputPtr; ++inputPtr)
{
  // some code
}
```

Keep in mind that the example you posted may not give the results you want. In your while loop condition, you're always performing a post-increment. When you're inside the loop, you've already passed the first character. Take this example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const char *str = "apple\0";
  const char *it = str;
  while(*it++)
  {
    cout << *it << '_';
  }
}
```

This outputs:

> p_p_l_e__

Notice the missing first character and the extra `_` underscore at the end. Check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380960/why-the-c-compiler-does-not-give-precedence-increment-operator-under-assigmen/8381173#8381173) if you're confused about pre-increment and post-increment operators.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming input isn't null terminated:

```
char* input = new char [input_max];
for (char* inputPtr = input; inputPtr < input + input_max; 
        inputPtr++) {
  inputPtr[0]++; 
}
```

for the null terminated case:

```
for (char* inputPtr = input; inputPtr[0]; inputPtr++) {
      inputPtr[0]++; 
}
```

but generally this is as good as you can get. Using `std::vector`, or `std::string` may enable cleaner and more elegant options though.

Comment: when could the input NOT be a null terminated?

Comment: not everything is a string. this can be a vector of numbers, or some sort of table and in these cases null is just another value

Comment: I haven't learned vectors yet, but good to keep in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
inputPtr = input; // init inputPtr always at the last moment.
while (*inputPtr != '\0') {      // Assume the string last with \0
       // some code
       inputPtr++; // After "some code" (instead of what you wrote).
}
```

Which is equivalent to the for-loop suggested by greatwolf. It's a personal choice.

Be careful, with both of your examples, you are testing the current position and then you increment. Therefore, you are using the next character!

Comment: So would a do-while be more appropriate if I stick with my examples?

Comment: A do-while would mean: test after executing some code, and as a consequence, always execute at least one time the loop. That could be useful if you want to consider the `\0` character for instance. But that would not be equivalent to your examples.